# Regex capture lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: java, regex, assertion, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I'm trying to write regex for the following situations:

```
badword%
%badword
%badword%
```

The `%` signs differ, depending on where they are. A `%` at the front needs a lookbehind to match letters preceding the word `badword` until it reaches a non-letter. Likewise, any `%` that is not at the front needs a lookahead to match letters following the word `badword` until it hits a non-letter.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve. If I have the following:

> Just a regular superbadwording sentece.

```
badword   # should match "badword", easy enough
badword%  # should match "badwording"
%badword% # should match "superbadwording"
```

At the same time. If I have a similar sentence:

> Here's another verybadword example.

```
badword   # should match "badword", easy enough
badword%  # should also match "badword"
%badword% # should match "verybadword"
```

I don't want to use spaces as the assertion capture groups. Assume that I want to capture `\w`.

Here's what I have so far, in Java:

```
String badword  = "%badword%";
String _badword = badword.replace("%", "");
badword = badword.replaceAll("^(?!%)%", "(?=\w)"); // match a % NOT at the beginning of a string, replace with look ahead that captures \w, not working
badword = badword.replaceAll("^%", "(?!=\w)"); // match a % at the beginning of a string, replace it with a look behind that captures \w, not working
System.out.println(badword); // ????
```

So, how can I accomplish this?

PS: Please don't assume the `%`'s are forced to the start and end of a match. If a `%` is the first character, then it will need a look behind, any and all other `%`'s are look aheads.

Comment: `(?!%)%` will always fail since it means "not followed by `%`, and literal `%` (that follows)". `(?!=\w)` is a negative lookahead and means "not followed by a literal `=` and a word character". In java backslashes must be escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it doesn't seem necessary to use lookaround, so you could just replace all `%` with `\w*`

Snippet:

```
String tested = "Just a regular superbadwording sentece.";
String bad = "%badword%";
bad = bad.replaceAll("%", "\\\\w*");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(bad);
Matcher m = p.matcher(tested);
while(m.find()) {
    String found = m.group();
    System.out.println(found);
}
```

\w doesn't match #,-,etc. so I think \S is better here

Answer (score 3):

```
badword = badword.replaceAll("^%", "(?!=\w)"); 
// match a % at the beginning of a string, replace it with a look behind 
//that captures \w, not working
```

`(?!=\w)` is a negative-look ahead for `=\w`, but it seems like you want a positive look-behind.  Secondly, lookaheads and lookbehinds are atomic, and thus inherently not capturing, so if I'm correct in my interpretation, you want:

`"(?<=(\\w+))"`.  You need the additional `()` for capturing.
For your first part, it would be: `"(?=(\\w+))`, and the first argument should be `"(?<!^)%"`.

PS: You need two backslashes for `\\w`, and you seem to want to match multiple characters, no?  If so, you would need `\\w+`.  Also, if you don't want to do this for every occurrence, then I suggest using `String.format()` instead of `replaceAll()`.

Comment: Putting a lookaround inside a capturing group doesn't solve anything.  The whole point of lookarounds is that they don't *consume* what they match, so even if the lookaround succeeds, all you're ever going to capture in that group is an empty string.

Comment: @AlanMoore Stupid typo, I did this on my phone.  Should be correct now.